# CSS perspective and translateZ not working properly in FF and Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a cover flow using css3 perspective and translateZ, **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/z3Skr/)**

It also has a transition effect when clicking through. It works perfect on Chrome and IE10, as well as mobile Safari 7.
However, it has few problems on Firefox and Desktop Safari.

1. On Firefox(latest 29.0.1), clicking on an image does not put it back to zero position (flat view).
   Also you cannot click through the layers below. Say when first image is the current image, you cannot click on the third one directly, unless you click the second and make it the current first.
2. On desktop Safari (5, on both PC and MAC), the transition works partly, not smooth but acceptable. The main problem is that no matter what image you clicks, it triggers the downloads immediately, while the code was supposed to download only when the image is the current one.

Structure very simple:
HTML

```
<div class="product-download">
    <div id="product-image">
        <img src="//placehold.it/360x259" /> <span class="download-title">Product Image</span>

    </div>
    <div id="in-situ-image">
        <img src="//placehold.it/360x259" /> <span class="download-title">In-Situ Image</span>

    </div>
    <div id="product-flyer">
        <img src="//placehold.it/360x259" /> <span class="download-title">Product Flyer</span>

    </div>
    <div id="data-sheet">
        <img src="//placehold.it/360x259" /> <span class="download-title">Data Sheet</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    width:100%;
}
.product-download {
    position:relative;
    width:900px !important;
    height:397px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform: perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(0px);
    -ms-transform: perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(0px);
    -moz-transform: perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(0px);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(0px);
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:30px;
}
.product-download > div {
    width:360px;
    height:289px;
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    transition: all 1s;
}
#product-image {
    z-index:9999;
    transform: perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(0px);
    -ms-transform: perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(0px);
    -moz-transform: perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(0px);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(0px);
}
#in-situ-image {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(-100px);
    -ms-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(-100px);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(-100px);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(-100px);
    z-index:5;
    left:150px;
}
#product-flyer {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(-100px);
    -ms-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(-100px);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(-100px);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(-100px);
    z-index:4;
    left:330px;
}
#data-sheet {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(-100px);
    -ms-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(-100px);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(-100px);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(-100px);
    z-index:3;
    left:510px;
}
.download-title {
    width:300px;
    height:30px;
    font: italic bold 18px/30px Helvetica, serif;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}
#product-image >span {
    display:block;
}
```

Jquery

```
$('.product-download div').click(function () {
    $(this).fadeTo('slow').css({
        'transform': 'perspective( 0px ) rotateY( 0deg ) translateZ(0px)',
            '-ms-transform': 'perspective( 0px ) rotateY( 0deg ) translateZ(0px)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'perspective( 0px ) rotateY( 0deg ) translateZ(0px)'
    }).css('z-index', '9999');
    $(this).prevAll().fadeTo('slow').css({
        'transform': 'perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 30deg ) translateZ(-100px)',
            '-ms-transform': 'perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 30deg ) translateZ(-100px)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 30deg ) translateZ(-100px)'
    }).css('z-index', '1');

    $(this).nextAll().each(function (index) {
        $(this).fadeTo('slow').css({
            'transform': 'perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -30deg ) translateZ(-100px)',
                '-ms-transform': 'perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -30deg ) translateZ(-100px)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -30deg ) translateZ(-100px)'
        }).css('z-index', '-' + index);

    });
    $('.download-title').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).children('span').eq(0).css('display', 'block');
    event.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).css('z-index') == 9999) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open('//placehold.it/200x200&text=DOWNLOAD', '_blank');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your applying the `z-index: 9999` immediately, which is why it always tests true and triggers the download (although why this varies by browser isn't clear).

You could:

- move the z-index declaration into the `fadeTo` function
- move the `if` test before the transitions (this is probably the easiest way)
- test on something other than z-index, perhaps use a class to explicitly identify the 'current' item, rather than relying on browser implementations of z-indexing

Comment: Nice point but didn't solve my problem, I did actually tried to use a current class at the beginning which didn't work either. The problem is the perspective, seems Firefox doesn't recognize 0px for perspective, changing that and makes it work. The transition for Safari is that for Safari lower than version 7 it needs vendor prefix -webkit.

Comment: Cool. In case this is useful to someone who finds this question later you should add your solution as an answer to your own question and mark it as the "accepted".